# Stacktrace:] with root cause

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have created a JSP Mysql And Bootstrap Crud App. When I click on the Update button function validation() will be invoked to update all the fields and after successful update it will redirect to another JSP page where all the details will be inserted into the phpMyAdmin database.

But I'm getting `Stacktrace:] with root cause` error. Also `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null` exception. I hope you will help me.

Here is the code:

**index.jsp**

```
 <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="com.dbconnectionutil.org.DbConnection"%>
<%@page import="java.net.ConnectException"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%
    Connection conn=null;

    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    ResultSet rs = null;

    String query = "SELECT * FROM newtable";

    try{

    conn = DbConnection.getConnection();

    ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);

    rs = ps.executeQuery();


    %>
    <div class="container bg-info" style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;">
    <h1>Jsp Mysql And Bootstrap Crud App</h1>

    <hr>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <form role="form" action="addRecord.jsp" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input type ="text" class="form-control" name="fname">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input type ="text" class="form-control" name="lname">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type ="email" class="form-control" name="email">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit">Add Record</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Crud Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <%
                    while(rs.next()){
                %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%=rs.getString("fname") %></td>
                        <td><%=rs.getString("lname") %></td>
                        <td><%=rs.getString("emailid") %></td>
                        <td>
                        <a href="editform.jsp?uid<%=rs.getInt("uid") %>" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Uptade</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <%
                }//while
                }//try
                catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();   
                }
                %>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**editform.jsp**

```
 <%@page import="com.dbconnectionutil.org.DbConnection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scaled=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<%
String uid = request.getParameter("uid");

int id = Integer.parseInt(uid);

Connection conn = null;

PreparedStatement ps = null;

ResultSet rs = null;

try{
    conn = DbConnection.getConnection();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM newtable WHERE uid='"+id+"'";

    ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);

    rs = ps.executeQuery();

%>
    <div class="container bg-info" style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;">
    <h1>Update Form</h1>
    <hr>
    <form action="" role="form">

    <%
        while(rs.next()){
    %>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=rs.getInt("uid") %>">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" value="<%=rs.getString("fname") %>" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lname" value="<%=rs.getString("lname") %>" class="form-control">
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="<%=rs.getString("emailid") %>" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <%
        }//while
    }//try

    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
        %>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Update</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements. What you have isn't one

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null` The message is pretty clear. You try to convert `null` to a number what is not possible

Comment: Do not use jdbc directly in the jsp. Learn about three tier architecture

Comment: And this has absolutely nothing to do with Bootstrap. Just because you have used a library doesn't mean you need to tag it here.

Comment: Jens, I am well aware about the problem, what I don't understand is why is "uid" returning null values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missing keyword `=` in the href attribute of a element inside `index.jsp`. That is why you get a `NumberFormatException`.

Replace `<a href="editform.jsp?uid<%=rs.getInt("uid") %>" >`

with

```
<a href="editform.jsp?uid=<%=rs.getInt("uid") %>" >
                         ^
```

---

And when you try doing the process of converting, it is necessary to catch exception:

```
try{
  int id = Integer.parseInt(uid);
}catch(NumberFormatException e){id = 0; } //maybe default value
```

**Important:** Keep in mind pieces of advice that @Jens gave on the comment.